# jQuery click handler performance - attach to class or each element

Tags: jquery, performance, click, handler

so I have x rows of data being loaded via ajax. at the end of each row, I am adding an edit button which will have a click handler to //do stuff.

```
$newTr.append(
    $("<img/>", {
        title: "edit task",
        "class": "edit clickable changeTask",
        src: "../../images/edit.png"
    })
)
```

Should I attach a click handler to the class:

```
$(document).on("click", ".changeTask", function(){ //do stuff
```

or should i attach it to each img:

```
$newTr.append(
    $("<img/>", {
        title: "edit task",
        "class": "edit clickable changeTask",
        src: "../../images/edit.png",
        click: function() {
            //do stuff
        }
    })
)
```

Note: this is strictly a performance question. Both ways work.  Also, if you could point towards a way to test this sort of thing myself, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your words "attaching it to the class" would be quicker.

Note that what you're actually doing is attaching a single handler to the `document`, which listens for an event to fire on any `.changeTask` element, by making use of event bubbling.

This differs from the second example, where you're attaching a separate event handler to *each* `<img />`.

The only potential performance hit here is if you're firing *thousands* of `click` events, as the handler on the `document` has to inspect each one to see if it's relevant. If possible, attach the handler as close as you can to the elements (as it'll have to filter less rubbish).  *This is irrelevant in 99.99999% of situations.*

Comment: No. You're gaining performance because you don't have to add an event every time you add a new `<img />`. You save memory because you don't have to keep 1,000,000 different event handlers in memory (instead you have only 1). You *lose* (the tiniest amount of) performance each time an event bubbles up to the `document` as you have to have to check whether the source of the event matches the selector (`.changeTask`) given.

Comment: Setting one click handler vs (x) amount of click handlers is definitely much quicker as Matt pointed out. Personally though, I prefer to attach to an ID. So if the table has an ID I would attach it to `$(#tableID).on('click', '.changeTask', function(){...});` That's just personal preference; I'm not sure about the performance comparison to using document over an ID, but I don't like attaching several different events to the document all the time.